# Selector in cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

So far I have this

```
const info = $('[data-style-name="Black"]').parent('li').html()
console.log(info)
```

and it logs the following html

```
<button data-url="/shop/jackets/ls0jgz4q1/t3i0gnxc9" 
    class="" 
    data-images="{&quot;detail_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/204642/ma/7P9KTS4_HEs.jpg&quot;,&quot;zoomed_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/204642/zo/7P9KTS4_HEs.jpg&quot;}" 
    data-style-name="Black" 
    data-style-id="30985" 
    data-sold-out="false" 
    data-description="Water resistant cotton with full zip closure and hidden snap placket. Velcro flap mesh hand pockets at lower front with dual top and side entry. Interior elastic shockcord at fixed hood and hem with velcro tab adjusters at cuffs. Woven logo labels at left pocket and back neck tab. "
>
    <img width="32" height="32" alt="Black" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/204642/sw/7P9KTS4_HEs.jpg">
</button>
<button data-url="/shop/jackets/ls0jgz4q1/t3i0gnxc9?alt=0" 
    class="" 
    data-images="{&quot;detail_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/204644/ma/ndcje1Lw83w.jpg&quot;,&quot;zoomed_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/204644/zo/ndcje1Lw83w.jpg&quot;}" 
    data-style-name="Black" 
    data-style-id="30985" 
    data-sold-out="false" 
    data-description="Water resistant cotton with full zip closure and hidden snap placket. Velcro flap mesh hand pockets at lower front with dual top and side entry. Interior elastic shockcord at fixed hood and hem with velcro tab adjusters at cuffs. Woven logo labels at left pocket and 
back neck tab. "
>
    <img width="32" height="32" alt="Black image 1" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/204644/sw/ndcje1Lw83w.jpg">
</button>
<button data-url="/shop/jackets/ls0jgz4q1/t3i0gnxc9?alt=1" 
    class="" 
    data-images="{&quot;detail_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/204645/ma/FUYxiNKaZ94.jpg&quot;,&quot;zoomed_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/204645/zo/FUYxiNKaZ94.jpg&quot;}" 
    data-style-name="Black" 
    data-style-id="30985" 
    data-sold-out="false" 
    data-description="Water resistant cotton with full zip closure and hidden snap placket. Velcro flap mesh hand pockets at lower front with dual top and side entry. Interior elastic shockcord at fixed hood and hem with velcro tab adjusters at cuffs. Woven logo labels at left pocket and back neck tab. "
>
    <img width="32" height="32" alt="Black image 2" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/204645/sw/FUYxiNKaZ94.jpg">
</button>
```

How do I get the value of the "data-style-id"

Comment: Which is the three elements do you want `data-style-id` for?

Comment: they all have the same value so it doesnt matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to access the `data-style-id` attribute for each matching element:

```
$('li > [data-style-name="Black"]').each((index, element) => {
    console.log($(element).attr("data-style-id"));
});
```

If you just want the value of the first one, you can use this:

```
let value = $('li > [data-style-name="Black"]').eq(0).attr("data-style-id");
console.log(value);
```